# change class of an element with media query ,angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

want to change a class of an element when the width of browser changes 
have that in my .ts

```
 matchMedia('(max-width: 400px)').addListener((mql => {
  if (mql.matches) {
    this.myclass = 'toggled';
}
}));
```

and in the html somthing like that:

```
<app-side-bar [ngClass]="myclass"></app-side-bar>
```

value of 'myclass' is changed but the HTML element(app-side-bar) is not getting updated -what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Angular does keep track of the the event that occurs when the browser size changes, it wont detect the change. You have to trigger it yourself:

You can do this by warpping the code inside `NgZone`:

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

// Inject NgZone in your constructor:    
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {

}

// Run the code that changes state inside the zone
matchMedia('(max-width: 400px)').addListener((mql => {
    if (mql.matches) {
        this.zone.run(() => {
            this.myclass = 'toggled';
        });
    }
}));
```

Comment: You are a god damn hero Sir -sooo many houres trying to figure that one  out,ty!! - so by writing 'this.zone.run I force an event correct?

Comment: Right. Angular keeps track of the changes done by the code executed inside `zone.run()` which triggers change detection.